# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - Running a nodejs process

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs application that needs to be run on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. The application forks child processes everytime there is a trigger from the application, that checks for the data in a MongoDB collection regularly. Let's say that due to high load, a new Beanstalk instance is scaled out and a child process is started in that new instance. All of a sudden, if the load is reduced, will the instance gracefully shutdown waiting for the child process to end or will it forcefully close all the application processes?

Update:

I had a look at the AWS link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-update-lifecycle-standby-detach/

I understand that there is a shutdown waiting period, however, AWS provides an option to copy the states and move to another autoscaling group, is that the option I should go with?

Regards,
Hari

Comment: EBS == Elastic Block Store. I believe your question is about Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @MarkB, I strongly suspect so, mainly since things aren't generally said to "run on"  EBS.  Could be "EC2" but it mostly sounds like beanstalk.  Edited and retagged.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant Elastic Beanstalk.